# Count records per day in a Django Model where date is Unix

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, django

I'm trying to create a query that counts how many queries per day there were on a certain Django table. I found a bunch of examples about it but none was dealing with Unix data. Here is what my model looks like:

```
class myData(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    query = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    unixtime = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'myData'
```

So the result i'm trying to get is something like: `{'27/06/2020': 10, '26/06/2020': 15 ... }`

The doubt i have is: should i use a raw MYSQL query or should i use Django's ORM?

I tried to make it with a raw query, but didn't get the expected output:

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(`unixtime`, '26.06.2020') as ndate,
       count(id) as query_count
from myData
group by ndate
```

But it gave the following output:

```
ndate      query_count
26/06/2020 1
26/06/2020 1
26/06/2020 1
26/06/2020 1
....
```

Can anyone help me out on this? It doesn't make the difference whether the query is made with raw mysql or Django ORM, i just need a simple way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up on how to use the [function `FROM_UNIXTIME()`](https://database.guide/from_unixtime-examples-mysql/), specially the allowed format string options.

Your query should probably be modified to something like this:

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtime, '%Y/%m/%d') as ndate,
       count(id) as query_count
from myData
group by ndate
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Yes, indeed that does work. I didn't understand i was not supposed to specify a date